# Making heading in bootstrap list item?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make something like this in bootstrap 3

[image]

This is what i have for now

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Cras justo odio
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Dapibus ac facilisis in
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Morbi leo risus
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What "heading" are you referring to? Are you talking about the blue subheadings, or the main (black) column headings?

Comment: I have two heading primary black, and secondary blue

Comment: You need to nest additional `<ul>`s under your subheading `<li>`s. Also, as of now, you have no heading tags specified, at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please check the jsfiddle example,

from the image you've provided:
css:

```
.borderless .list-group-item {
    border: none;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="list-group borderless">
  <li class="nav-header disabled"><a>Header A</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Cras justo odio
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Dapibus ac facilisis in
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Morbi leo risus
  </li>
</ul>
```

you can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Stan119/womcjc3n/2/)

if you will have some questions please don't hesitate to ask, or comment the answer

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't really get what you want,
please check the answer one more time.